# For Lasso regression, does increasing the tuning parameter $\lambda$ result in more significant coefficients?

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, regularization, hyperparameter

In Lasso regression, for a sparse estimate of coefficients $\beta$, we have:

$$
\hat{\beta}(\lambda) = \arg \min_b \Bigl\{\frac{1}{2} ||y-Xb||^2_{2} + \lambda||b||_1\Bigl\}
$$

Then, define $V_j = \sup\Bigl\{\lambda: \hat{\beta}_j(\lambda) \neq 0 \Bigl\}$.

This is suppose to encapsulate the point $\lambda$ on the Lasso solution path where the feature $X_j$ first enters the model. Overall, we want $V_j$ to be large for most signals and small for most of the null variables.

Can anyone shed light why $V_j$ is the first point $\lambda$ where $X_j$ enters the model? Thanks.

For example, does the graph look like the first one, sloping DOWN to the right, or the second one, sloping UP to the right?:

[image]

or [image]

?

Comment: why Vj is the first point λ where Xj enters the model... it is by definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum

Comment: Why is it defined in supremum? Supremum is like the least upper bound or maximum, so why not infimum, which gives the greatest lower bound? How exactly does the graph look like here?

Comment: Are the graphs sloping downwards?

Comment: Variables enter the model while you *decrease* the $\lambda$. 

So for $\lambda$ above the point that the variable enters the model there is no $\beta \neq 0$. 

Thus the point that the variable enters the model is an upper bound for the set $\lbrace  \lambda:\hat{\beta}(\lambda) \neq 0\rbrace$ (since above the $\lambda$ at that point, there is no $\beta \neq 0$).

More precisely it is the lowest of such upper bound (because any lower you will find the $X$ entering the model and you have a case of $\beta \neq 0$).

Comment: Should it not be the infimum then?

Comment: @user321627 where did you encounter $V_j$?

Comment: I have attached two photos of sample paths. Can you tell me which one is the right one corresponding to the formulation? Is it the one sloping to the right?

Comment: @user321627 It's the first one. (Notice that it is indexed by $\lambda$.) I'm really interested in this $V_j$ term. Did you encounter it in a paper? I vaguely remember coming across it before, but I can't remember the context.

Comment: I encountered it in a talk regarding high-dimensional variable selection at JASA. I don't remember the exact talk, I can dig it up for you if you'd like.

Comment: The graphs can be seen as equivalent. Or at least, the difference between sloping up and down is in the inverted x-scale. *Also the second picture use as x-scale the value of $\vert\vert \beta(\lambda) \vert\vert$ and the first uses $\lambda$ but they have a monotonic relationship.* For the supremum thing... more intuitive than the term 'least upper bound' is 'tightest upper bound'.

Comment: The term $V_j$ occurs, at least, in the work on controlling FDR by creating a statistic based on the $V_j$' s at which a variables enters the model and in comparison with modeled data.  https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1438606853

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Aha! It was indeed in the context of knockoffs that I saw. Thanks for pointing that out!